# Cannot Format USB using CMD (Location Path: Unavailable ; No Disk Volume)

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

USB showing partition but can't select.
USB has no volume and the Location Path is Unavailable.

[image: Can't Select Partition]

[image: No Volume and Location Path]

Comment: `select partition 1`

Answer (score 0):

Using diskparts `clean` command to completely wipe the disk partition table. Make sure you selected the correct disk.

Comment: Hi, I already tried clean it also but still I always get an error like " Virtual Disk Service error: There is no media in the device" and "Diskpart has encountered an error: The device is not ready."

Comment: hm. Let's try to run it on another PC then.

Answer (score 0):

I had a "similar" issue. After some searching the interwebs I found a couple articles.

https://www.diskpart.com/format-disk/diskpart-has-encountered-an-error-access-is-denied.html

The above mentioned three items to check.

1. check the Event log for a specific error.
2. Make sure you have run DiskPart (CMD) as admin.
3. And to check that the registry doesn't have the disk as "Read-Only"

I was running as admin.

The Registry Entry didn't exist for me, so a no go there.
HKLM:/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Control/StorageDevicePolicies

My event log (System), which I should have checked first, error was:
`Cannot zero sectors on disk \\?\PhysicalDrive3. Error code: 5@0101000F`

Disk Part Details for the disk:

```
DISKPART> detail disk

Generic Flash Disk USB Device
Disk ID: {A77B501C-3C01-4061-A139-310564D197EF}
Type   : USB
Status : Online
Path   : 0
Target : 0
LUN ID : 0
Location Path : UNAVAILABLE
Current Read-only State : No
Read-only  : No
Boot Disk  : No
Pagefile Disk  : No
Hibernation File Disk  : No
Crashdump Disk  : No
Clustered Disk  : No

  Volume ###  Ltr  Label        Fs     Type        Size     Status     Info
  ----------  ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volume 8     F                       Removable       0 B  Unusable
```

After searching for the "Cannot zero sectors Error code: 5@0101000F" I found this the second article: https://www.elevenforum.com/t/running-a-diskpart-clean-command-fails-frequently-in-current-win-11-version.4877/

Skimming through this article I tried the following from the posts

```
DISKPART> convert gpt
DISKPART> clean all
```

So far no Access Denied on a CLEAN ALL.

If this fails I will update this accordingly.

I hope this helps.